# adb devices command and eclipse don't recognize my sony ericsson xperia x10

Tags: android, adb, x10

I am using Windows xp.

adb devices command doesn't show my xperia x10 and 
eclipse doesn't recognize my xperia x10
I have htc magic and it works fine.

I downloaded driver from:
http://developer.sonyericsson.com/community/docs/DOC-3328#cf

and I installed driver without problems and I don't have for example yellow question mark on driver in device manager.and it is very recent ()

I downloaded sony ericsson applications like Sony_Ericsson_PC_Companion_2.00.134.exe
and Update_Service_Setup-2.10.5.11.exe
and they can detect my phone

but other apps can't detect my phone
for example:
adb devices command cant detect my phone
eclipse and android plug in cant detect my phone
apk installer app cant detect my phone

note:
I followed this documentation from Sony ericsson in driver installation:
http://developer.sonyericsson.com/community/docs/DOC-3496#cf

and I think that I noticed some thing mah help in solving this problem

in this documentation, they say that I should replace default adb.exe with another one that sony ericsson developed and this file is included in driver zip file.

but I didn't find this file in driver zip file that I downloaded from sony ericsson

if it is true
then if someone gave this missing file, may be my problem will be solved.

Answer (score 4):

**Some of the links here are dead** They have moved the *"drivers"* to: http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/search-downloads/driver?cc=gb&lc=en

This was the obvious first set of drivers I tried, however they would not "take" when targeting them during the "Update Driver" process.  These I believe are the same drivers that are installed when the ***Sony Ericsson PC Companion*** software is installed, it does solve the problem of the device not being recognized in the Device Manager.  Problem is, `adb devices` will **still** not return a device ID for the connected device!

*However!*

The drivers available within **FlashTool version 0.3.0.0** (`/drivers/`) did.  FlashTool is the only sane way to work with the X10.  Allows for 1 button flashing, rooting, optimization, APK side loading, and much more.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=920746

Unzip FlashTool, and within the `/drivers/` directory, you will find the following:

- `ggsetup-2.2.0.11.exe` - "Gordon's Gate FlashTool Drivers"
- `X8_ADB_drivers.zip` - "X8 adb drivers!"
- `X10_ADB_drivers.zip` - "X10 adb drivers!"
- `X10_mini_ADB_drivers.zip` - "X10mini adb drivers!"

Answer (score 3):

Dear Hisham Bakr, please try flow steps:

```
Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to install apk files, try [Android Injector](http://www.harmonyhollow.net/android_injector.shtml)

It is basically a gui shell for adb and I've had success using it on my daughter's x10.

---

Problem is, that unless you have the adb driver working, nothing will be injected.  The FlashTool has an APK installer within the UI of the app.  On the other-hand you could just mount the SD card (no x10 adb driver needed), copy over the apk, and execute it using a file manager like Astro to launch it.

Unfortunately, welcome to the catch 22 that we have all been stuck with while doing xRecovery installs on the Xperia x10 since ClockworkMOD is incompatible with the device.  The x10 is distributed by AT&T in the states, which means that a stock device will not allow the installations of non-marketplace apps.  Even if you specific version of OS allows you to check "OK" in the settings to allow non-marketplace APK installs.

In this case, you need to "Re-brand/Unlock" the device and the only way one can do this is with the x10adb driver that comes with the FlashTool.  From there you can "root", and flash!

Hope this has all been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, although I installed every driver required and the PC Companion application adb couldn't detect my Xperia Ray so after hours of unsuccessful attempts I installed an application named EasyTether from here:
http://easytether.blogspot.com/2010/10/easytether-drivers.html
I followed all the instructions and finally I could install my first android application to my phone.