# sony ericsson xperia x10 not showing in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, sony-xperia

I want to test my android app on my xperia x10 device but its not showing up in the device list. I have downloaded the correct drivers but when I try to install them trough the device manager it says "Windows was unable to install your SEMC HSUSB Device".

I have USB debugging activated.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first of all try to uninstall all your Sony device drivers because
   the drivers which you downloaded is only for data transfer(backup
   and transfer files) but not for debugging.
2. Second if you really want to test you app on your Sony Device then
   you need to download the usb debug drivers of Sony x10
3. Click this
   [link](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/).
4. After downloading the debug drivers from the above link check for the debug mode is checked and then connect your device .
5. After connecting the device you need to do slight changes in the Android Virtual Device Manager(AVD).
6. By default your application will execute on a user defined emulator
   for this you need to set the AVD to prompt  you every time you execute
   the application.
7. In this way you could select your device on the dialog box that
   appears and the application is then executed on your device instead
   of the emulator

Comment: 1. no driver is installed yet, 2. that link is what driver I already downloaded but cant install, 4. Unable to install driver as mentioned in question.

Comment: @jt123 be patient and tell me your system configuration

Comment: I am patient, I have been trying things for hours. I have a windows 8.1 pro 64-bit, anything else you wish to know?

Comment: try this direct [link](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/sony-ericsson-x10-drivers/) for the debugging driver for your phone. Download this driver its of 6MB install and tell me the progress if not follow this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1193066)

Comment: The first link gives me the error message I mention in the question and the second link tells me `found driver but encountered a problem ... the hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file, the file is likely corrupt or victim of tampering`

Comment: Okay it seems the driver is getting compatibility issues with your Operating System as The above first link goes easy on Windows 7 .Try to get in touch with your Sony Support team using live chat if available in your country else if you want to avoid that then  please try posting this question on this [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/) they will give u the best possible answer

Comment: @jt123 As you can see [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) there's no driver for win 8 shown

Answer (score 2):

USB Debugging should be ON and then,

> Try to reset the adb (DDMS Perspective --> Devices Tab --> Small
>   Triangle on right side(Last option) --> Reset adb)

The drivers are here:

http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads/download/dw-x10drivers?cc=gb&lc=en

Use `adb devices` from command line to know if you've got the phone connected correctly.

Still have a problem then I have read a solution which says -

- *From the device-manager, got the hardware-id of the device that
  failed to install (under details, you can get the hardware-id, in my
  case these Hardware-Id's were listed:
  USB\VID_0FCE&PID_612E&REV_0224&MI_01 USB\VID_0FCE&PID_612E&MI_01 I
  then opened the inf-file (sa0101usb.inf), and under the sections:
  [SEMC.NTx86] and [SEMC.NTamd64] I added a new entry with the new
  key...*

i.e. -

```
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_612E&MI_01
```

Then installing the drivers worked like a charm...

More POSTS for the solution can be found at - [eclipse-dont-recognize-my-sony-ericsson-xperia-x10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883255/adb-devices-command-and-eclipse-dont-recognize-my-sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-ple?rq=1).

Comment: debug is on, when I reser adb it says `Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. use `adb devices` from command line how? I get `'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command ... `, i changed sa0101usb.inf and still same message like in the question. I have read the POSTS you linked before and they did not help me eather.

Comment: Open `Task Manager` and kill all the process that are `adb.exe` and then restart the eclipse and start adb again.

Comment: ok, adb started when i restarted eclipse but this changed nothing :( eclipse even tell me `adb is running normally.` in the console

Comment: Use "Android Device Chooser" from eclipse to select your device from their. Also make sure that you installed the correct drivers from the link that is mentioned in the answer and then restarted your PC after driver install.

Comment: "Android Device Chooser" is empty, probably because of the error I get when trying to install the driver you linked.

Comment: Your very first problem is system is unable to install the driver for your device. No driver means no USB debugging. Use the link as a help to install the driver first - http://androidforums.com/sony-ericsson-xperia-x10/205801-how-install-usb-driver-sony-ericsson-x10.html

Comment: I ended up on that page earlier and what I am doing is finding the device with an error in the device manager and updating its drivers by manually picking from where to get them. Thne I pick the extracted folder of what I downloaded from your link. The debug drivers for sony ericsson x10 (http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/sony-ericsson-x10-drivers/). I guess I'm doing this right?

Comment: yes manually install the drivers and then you will get the chooser for your device in eclipse only after successful install.

Comment: God bless you!! I can confirm this procedure works with Windows 7 64 bit... Download the original driver from Sony page http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/sony-ericsson-x10-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for win8.1 64
and i solved it by getting hardware ids of the device it was USB\VID_0FCE&PID_612E&MI_01
and from Update Driver Software/Browse my computer for driver software/ Let me pick from a list ...
And selected Samsung Android ADB Interface and its worked for me 
Think that will be usefull
:)