# Eclipse doesn't detect Sony Xperia J

Tags: android, eclipse, sony, sony-xperia

I have installed Google USB Driver and PC Companion, I set USB mass mode and enable debugging. In my project manifest I set debugging too. But eclipse still doesn't detect my phone. What else could be the reason? Thanks for any help

Edit:

I found the reason, stupid mistake, my application is API19.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883255/adb-devices-command-and-eclipse-dont-recognize-my-sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-ple

Comment: Open up the command prompt, type "adb devices" and press enter. Is your device listed there? Also, is USB debugging enabled on the device? Is the device's USB connection set to MTP?

Comment: I don't know if it change anything but I have my phone in Devices tab in eclipse, but when I launch app, it doesn't detect

Comment: what the min version of your app and device.

Comment: if the device is shown in ddms,the it could be the issue. can i have the screen shot of your DDMS where device is showing.

Comment: I just saw diffrent API level, but thank you. Is any possibility to solve it?

Comment: Ok, I changed in manifest to test :) works

Answer (score 0):

This might not seem like a likely problem but have you tried a different cable? I had days of headaches trying to solve a similar problem and found that the cable had broken.

Comment: Have you tried a different one? Or tried the same cable on a different device?

Comment: But as I wrote above, I have my phone in Devices tab in eclipse, but when I launch app, it doesn't detect